# Allow a group to impersonate others using sudo, but don't allow them to become root

Tags: centos, sudo

We have a user support group and want to allow them to login to non-root users via `sudo`.

```
%user-support  ALL = (ALL) /bin/bash, !/bin/bash *root*
```

We put the above code in `/etc/sudoers.d`, and the user support group can log in to other users. However, they can also log in to root using the `sudo -u root -i` command.

Is there a way to block the user support group from becoming root?

Allow the user-support login to other users except for root.

Answer (score 2):

`= (ALL)` is the part that specifies the list of users, as which the configured commands can be run as.

For example:

```
# who            # where     # whoas          #what
user1            ALL       = (user2)        : /bin/ls
%group1          alpha     = (%group2)      : /bin/cp
```

`user1` can run `sudo -u user2 ls` on all hosts, that have this configuration

All users in the group `group1` can run cp via sudo only on host `alpha` as user in `group2`

Instead of using unix-/ldap-groups, `User_Alias` could be used as well to define "groups".